# Display javaFX gui elements inline

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I have some troubles with finding answer how to display two elements in the same line in JavaFX gui. I want to display radio buttons in the same line with 50% width and also make the same with two textfields.

I add part of my code:

```
primaryStage.setTitle("Acoustic Insulation");

        ToggleGroup signalGroup = new ToggleGroup();
        final RadioButton radioSweep = new RadioButton("Sweep");
        radioSweep.setToggleGroup(signalGroup);
        radioSweep.setStyle(" -fx-display:inline-block ");

        final RadioButton radioSin = new RadioButton("Sin");
        radioSin.setToggleGroup(signalGroup);
        radioSin.setStyle(" -fx-display:inline-block ");

        Label frequencyLabel = new Label("Frequency:");
        final TextField frequencyText = new TextField();

        Label timeLabel = new Label("Set time [s]:");
        final TextField timeText = new TextField();

        Button startBtn = new Button();
        startBtn.setText("START");
```

and actual view:

[image]

Comment: What kind of container are you using? you could use a `HBox`

Comment: I have something like: public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

Comment: You need to read about JavaFX layout panes: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/layout-tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    GridPane root = new GridPane();
    root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    root.setHgap(12);

    HBox box = new HBox();
    box.getChildren().addAll(radioSweep, radioSin);
    box.setSpacing(50);
    box.setPrefWidth(200);

    HBox box1 = new HBox();
    box1.getChildren().addAll(frequencyText, timeText);
    box1.setSpacing(12);
    box1.setPrefWidth(200);

    root.add(box, 0, 0);
    root.add(box1, 1, 0);

    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 500);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you just need to change the width of the border.

`startBtn.setStyle("-fx-border-width: 0 3 3 0;");`